Hand grabbing and interaction with 3D objects in VR for visionOS
I make a 3D URP project in ( Virtual reality - fully immersive for VisionOS ) Unity 2022.3.28f1 version. Create a basic project with import and use of XR Hands and XR Interaction Toolkit and in this project while run it in simulator and real visionOS device i have facing an issue that the 3D objects is not grabbable with our hands at the same time UI is interactable with hands even i have test unity’s template also but the same issue coming there, Another thing is the 3D objects is interactable and grabbable from Meta Quest controllers while testing it in unity’s simulator.
I'm configure all the things but the hand grabbing is not working, your help will be appreciated, if you can.
